# firestore on nodejs server is very slow

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore with Nodejs (expressjs framework) and the first simple request takes **more than 25 seconds!**

and if i get the same request with JavaScript in the client-side or with Rest API tool like (postman) i get the data immediately! no problem!
So what is the issue here?

*this is the code:*

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();


const admin = require("firebase-admin");

const serviceAccount = require("../privte/quiztestweb-firebase-adminsdk-vd7zn-1a3a896f60.json");

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://quiztestweb.firebaseio.com"
});

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {

  let db = admin.firestore();

  db.collection("/quizzes/quiz_1/tests/").get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
      });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });

  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I'm noticing that your route sends a response to the client before the `get()` is complete.  Is that really what you want?  That doesn't seem right.  Also, I don't see any information data here on how you are benchmarking the response, so your measurement is very unclear to me.

Comment: this is just an example .. because i'm waiting the data from console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Finally!**

i solve this issue by **removing the new version** of firebase package  and **replace it with an older one!**

> ((but it's still just a temporary solution .. until fixed by firebase
>   developers))